# How do I find all controls of a particular type from a page inside a master page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, telerik, master-pages

I have to enable/disable via javascript all RadComboBoxes from my page, which is inside a master page. I was pointed to this simple tutorial (http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/general/how-to-create-a-javascript-array-of-all-particular-radcontrols-on-the-page.aspx), but instead of finding all telerik RadControls in the page, it returns me only the RadControls of the master page. There's something I'm missing to point out that I want the controls of the page inside the master page?

This is what I have now (allRadControls return me the RadSplitter, RadPane ans RadButtons from my master page)

```
 function DisableSave(habilita, botao) {
                    var btSalvar = $find(botao);
                    if (btSalvar != null) {
                        var allRadControls = $telerik.radControls;
                        if (habilita == "True") {
                            btSalvar.set_enabled(true);
                            $("#<%=pnlPrincipal.ClientID%>").find("input,a,textarea,table").attr("disabled", false);
                        }
                        else {
                            btSalvar.set_enabled(false);
                            $("#<%=pnlPrincipal.ClientID%>").find("input,a,textarea,table").attr("disabled", true);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: you are using client side script to return server side information. I think you just need to look at what the client is seeing.

Comment: Javascript is run on the client, and has no knowledge of master pages and content pages. Is `$("#<%=pnlPrincipal.ClientID%>")` rendered from your master page? Try `$("input,a,textarea,table").prop("disabled", true);`

Answer (score 0):

RadComboBox exposes an array at client-side that contains all RadComboBox instances. This array can be accessed like:

Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.ComboBoxes

For example:

If RadComboBox controls are embedded in another control, you can simply get these controls from the array described above.

Here is an example of radcombobox nested inside a Grid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" ...>    
    ...     
    <EditItemTemplate>        
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>        
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox2" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>        
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox3" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>    
    </EditItemTemplate>   
... </telerik:RadGrid>
```

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    function pageLoad() {
        var combo1 = Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.ComboBoxes[0];
        var combo2 = Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.ComboBoxes[1];
        var combo3 = Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.ComboBoxes[2];
    }
</script>
```

Here is the help documentation link:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-basics.html

Hope this helps...